# How to remove escape character while writing data from URL into JSON files in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write json data into file with python, But when it is written into file i am seeing some extra escape character(\) comming in between each data

I am writing by json data like this:-

```
 with open(Json_file_name, 'a') as fp:
      json.dump(One_message, fp,indent = 2)
```

I am receiving the data from URL like this :-

```
{"abc":{"name":"syz","last_nm":"exctrccc"}}
```

But while writing this data escape character in appering

```
{\"abc\":{\"name\":\"syz\\\\\"\","last_nm":"exctrccc"}}
```

Can you guide me, how can i prevent this escape character while writing

Comment: Can you show what `one_message` is, exactly? When you do `print(one_message)`?

Comment: print(One_message)

Comment: {"abc":{"name":"syz","last_nm":"exctrccc"}}

Comment: from actual data i am removing replace("b'","",1) and forming one_message variable

Comment: when i run through your code  which data (json)you added, i dont find any escape character ,it works fine..